# Pandas Read_CSV with Multiline fields

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a data file, containing a header row that is Pipe delimited and all fields are contained within quotes.  Additionally, fields within my file may contain a carriage return and are split over multiple lines.

Example File:

```
"Unique_Id"|"AnotherField"|"TextFieldWithCarriageReturn"|"EmptyField"
"RecordID1"|"SomeValue"|"This is an example field log, contained within is a carriage return,
here is the second line of this field"|""
"RecordID2"|"SomeValue2"|"Same Field but without a carriage return"|""
```

No matter what I try, I am unable to get pandas to stop treating the carriage return as a new record identifier.

`pd.read_csv('Data/Test.csv', sep='|', header=0)`

Why is Pandas ignoring the | as a seperator and how can I resolve this issue?

Any help, greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your code with the csv is working for me, the multi line is not considered as a new line. What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: im using version 0.25.1

Answer (score 0):

Further to my comment, here's the output of the code, what output are you getting?

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep='|', header=0)
print(df)

   Unique_Id AnotherField                        TextFieldWithCarriageReturn  EmptyField
0  RecordID1    SomeValue  This is an example field log, contained within...         NaN
1  RecordID2   SomeValue2           Same Field but without a carriage return         NaN
```